# How to make URL coming in via Bluetooth open in browser?

Tags: browser, bluetooth, bookmarks

When receiving an URL from Nokia phone, my Galaxy 3 shows the URL as text file and I need to first open it via Opera browser, then manually select the whole URL and only then I can open it all (for some reason Opera lacks "Select All"...).

So, what do I need to install to make this go like it goes on Nokia phones, ie. receive URL, tap to open in browser, done?

Opera is not the default handler, but because Android handles incoming link like any text file on file system, the default browser is not offered at all. Picking the other option works even less.

Comment: Is Opera set as your "default" browser or are you selecting it from a list of applications to open the link with?

Comment: Selecting form a list. The default browser is not listed at all, and even in Opera the file opens like a text file on filesystem.